# symfony 5 web debug toolbar showing anonymous and cannot redirect after onAuthenticationSuccess

Tags: reactjs, symfony5

I have been following along with the following Symfony tutorials, but I believe they are using version 4 and I am using version 5. They reach a point in the tutorial which shows that the web debug toolbar shows the user's email logged and they even pointed out that if you see logged as anonymous, then just refresh. I did refresh, but it still shows as anon.

[image: web debug toolbar status]

As you can see by the following screen shot, login was successful and it shows the correct username as well:

[image: console logs]

I started to watch the first part of the tutorial - listed below - when I reached a point in the second part that pointed out that I should watch the first part, which made sense, that I might have missed something, but that was an even older version of Symfony and things have changed in version 5.

[First part of the tutorial](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-security/make-user)
[Second part of the tutorial](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-security/production-docs)

After going through the tutorials, I still have the web debug tool showing anon. Now, I am using React as a form to POST the email and password - see next screen shot - would that effect how the web debug toolbar, but I do not see how, because the console shows that the system knows the user.

[image: React login form]

Does anyone know a config that needs to be changed?

I have tried changing the following within src\Security\TokenAuthenticator - getUser from:

```
        return $this->em->getRepository(User::class)
        ->findOneBy(['apiToken' => $credentials])
        ;
```

To:

```
return $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);
```

But no change, still shows anon

Also, as the subject states, I cannot redirect via onAuthenticationSuccess

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    // on success, let the request continue
    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_homepage'));
}
```

I do not see why this does not work. Again, is it because I am posting via a React app?

Answer (score 0):

Turns that it is because I am running an older version of the browser Firefox and the log in is working. You can see by the screen shot of both Firefox and Chrome, that it is working Chrome

[image: screen shot of both Chrome and Firefox browsers]

As far as the redirect goes, PHPStorm was saying that I did not have urlGenerator available in the TokenAuthenticator class. As a result, I should have noticed before and this is what I did to correct it:

In my src\Security\TokenAuthenticator I have the following:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
```

In my constructor:

```
private $em;
private $urlGenerator;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
}
```

My onAuthenticationSuccess:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    // on success, let the request continue
    // redirect to some "app_homepage" route - of wherever you want
    return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_homepage'));
}
```

But it is still not working

I have tried

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

private $redirectResponse;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, RedirectResponse   $redirectResponse)
{
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->redirectResponse = $redirectResponse;
}

public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    // on success, let the request continue
    // redirect to some "app_homepage" route - of wherever you want
    return $this->redirectResponse->redirectToRoute('app_homepage');
}
```

But PHPStorm tells me that it cannot find method redirectToRoute within class RedirectResponse

The only thing that I have found to work with redirecting users to the home page after successful is login, is within my React login app. I have an async to my handleClick method, after the fetch POST, I have a setTimeout of 3000 that uses a plain javascript:

```
window.location.href = '/';
```

I would love to know the answer to why I cannot redirect via the Authenticator class that I have created, but at least someone who is using Firefox will not have to wonder why their web debug tool is not showing that the user has successfully logged in while still showing anon